# Basic math issue in JavaScript/jQuery - Variable remembering value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that, for example, has a number 3 on it.  If user presses it, it goes to 4.  If they press again, it should go BACK to 3.  Instead, it goes to 2.  The problem is that when I'm trying to set the main variable with the new total, it is not saving the value.  Can someone see what is happening?

Here is jQuery/JS:

```
    var $this = $(this),
    was_voted = $this.data('wasvoted'),
    vote_total = $this.data('vote_total');
    $.ajax({
        // edited
        },

        success : function(data) {


            if (was_voted == 1) {
                $this.vote_total = vote_total - 1;
                $this.data('wasvoted', 0);
            } else if (was_voted == 0) {
                $this.vote_total = vote_total + 1;
                $this.data('wasvoted', 1);
            }

            vote_total = $this.vote_total;

            $this.find('.vote_total').text($this.vote_total);

        }
    });
```

Comment: where are you setting `was_voted` ?

Comment: @sansix, that was removed, but I'll add it.

Comment: You've got a significant syntax error in your pseudo code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's happening there with your variable names. Is $this.vote_total defined elsewhere? That won't change the data attribute (unless I'm mistaken). Try this:

```
var $this = $(this),
    was_voted = $this.data('wasvoted'),
    vote_total = $this.data('vote_total');
    $.ajax({
        // edited
        },

        success : function(data) {
            if (was_voted == 1) {
                vote_total --;
            } else if (was_voted == 0) {
                vote_total ++;
            }
            $this.data('vote_total', vote_total);
            $this.find('.vote_total').text(vote_total);

        }
    });
```

I can't test it so sorry for any typos!